# J1 visa-Reapply

Tags: j-visa

I attended the J1 visa interview on 8th June 2017. I got my visa issued yesterday 11th July 17. In the visa, they have given expiration date as 9th August 2017. Now I have amended DS2019 certificate, asking to start on 4th August. Should I apply for J1 visa again?

Comment: When do you plan to travel?  If you will arrive before 4 August, or indeed on any day up to and including 9 August, you don't need a new visa.